# Ошибка при компиляции кода в создание 2D игры на андроид, на Unity5

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

При создание 2D игры на андроид произошла ошибка в unity5, помогите с вопросом, вот код:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'SpriteRenderer' attached to the 
"Play" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a SpriteRenderer to the game object "Play". Or your 
script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.SpriteRenderer.set_sprite (UnityEngine.Sprite value) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/bindings_old/common/Core/SpritesBindings.gen.cs:263)
Button.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Scripts/Button.cs:9)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)
```

Comment: У вас в коде, скорее всего, есть строка GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(), но при этом данный компонент не прикреплен к игровому объекту, на котором висит этот скрипт. Обновите вопрос: добавьте код и скриншот инспектора игрового объекта с данным скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто добавить компонент, Sprite Renderer в Unity.